# How can I delete my duplicate Ubuntu install?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I made a mistake while installing Ubuntu, so I had to install it twice. Unfortunately, I now have two identical installs of Ubuntu. I am trying to use GParted to delete the partitions with the install but I am getting this error: `Unable to delete /dev/sda10! Please unmount any logical partitions having a number higher than 10`. This is how my partitioning table look in GParted: [image: Gparted]

sda1 & sda2 is Windows, sda4 is a swap area, sda10-12 is the Ubuntu installation I don't use, sda13&14 is the Ubuntu installation I am using, and sda5-9 is a Kali installation I occasionally use and don't want to delete.

This is the output I got when I ran `df` to double check that I was booting from sda13&14.

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4006212       0   4006212   0% /dev
tmpfs             805276    9992    795284   2% /run
/dev/sda14      62945204 7059752  52664972  12% /
tmpfs            4026368    6496   4019872   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4026368       0   4026368   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda13        291252    3684    287568   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             805276      12    805264   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs             805276      32    805244   1% /run/user/1000
```

What I want to do is to delete sda10-12 and merge the free space into sda14. But as mentioned I am getting an error message when trying to delete them. I still have the Ubuntu Live USB which I can boot from, but I don't want to destroy any of my other OS's. So what I am wondering is, how can I safely accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Manipulating partitions is inherently unsafe. Something can go wrong, the user can make a mistake, and so on. With that out of the way, you can use the Ubuntu live USB to delete and merge partitions, just be extra careful, and backup stuff you can't lose.

Comment: @mikewhatever Okay, I'll try that

Comment: @mikewhatever I suggest posting something like that as an answer.

Comment: This happens because some partitions to the right of the one you want to delete (which is presumably not mounted itself) are mounted. If you delete a partition to the left of them while they are mounted, they may be corrupted, so Gparted refuses to take the risk (although I agree with mikewhatever that repartitioning is always risky). The solution is to use Gparted from a live environment when none of the partitions on the drive are mounted, as in the linked post